# Can we add "rapidssl" to the list of banned words please?

Tags: feature-request, spam

I'm sick of deleting the spam we get from their millions of 'resellers'.

Comment: I made the mistake of blogging about installing SSL certs on my old blog a few years ago. RapidSSL lowlifes took advantage of that with comment spam for many moons afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Is this still an issue? If so then email `team@stackexchange.com` to get it added to the blacklist.

Please be absolutely sure it's an ongoing, recurring, pernicious issue before escalating directly to a blacklist.

Comment: I haven't seen much lately (not enough to justify a ban), but I'll let you know if I see any in the coming weeks.